# Android - Facebook Sharing Uncertainty (Text)

Tags: android, facebook, sharing

The code below works to share an image. I'm having problems adding text to it without using a FB graph (which I dont want to do at this point). This code shares an image straight to Facebook but:

1) how do I also share text? I know how to do one or the other but cant seem to figure out both.

2) is it possible to have Facebookj scale the image?

Thank you for your help.

```
int imageToShare = getResources().getIdentifier(myCard.getImageId(),"drawable","com.gjnave.carddisplayertemplate");     
    Uri cardImageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.gjnave.carddisplayertemplate/" + imageToShare);
    bmpImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), cardImageUri);
    performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO, false);
```

Comment: FB will scale the image for you generally on their servers.

Comment: re: share text, I think that you need to have the posting permission given to you via the user to pre-populate the share box.